# Allocating to groups in order of preference

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out how to assign a pool of people to a job with a specific number of openings based on qualification. In order of qualification, I want to first hire PhD level people, then Master's level, then Bachelor's level.

For instance, for Job A, I have 6 positions to fill (`needed`), and a pool of 4 PhDs (`app_phd`), 1 Master's (`app_ma`), and 3 Bachelor's-level (`app_ba`) applicants. So, I will hire 4 PhDs (`hire_phd`), 1 Master's (`hire_ma`), and 1 Bachelor's-level (`hire_ba`) applicant for this job.

My data frame showing the applicants and available openings is:

```
data.frame(job = c("a","b","c","d"),
           needed = c(6,4,3,2),
           app_phd = c(4,4,0,1),
           app_ma = c(1,1,1,1),
           app_ba = c(3,2,6,1))

  job needed app_phd app_ma app_ba
1   a      6       4      1      3
2   b      4       4      1      2
3   c      3       0      1      6
4   d      2       1      1      1
```

And my desired output is:

```
data.frame(job = c("a","b","c","d"),
           needed = c(6,4,3,2),
           app_phd = c(4,4,0,1),
           app_ma = c(1,1,1,1),
           app_ba = c(3,2,6,1),
           hired_phd = c(4,4,0,1),
           hired_ma = c(1,0,1,1),
           hired_ba = c(1,0,2,0))

  job needed app_phd app_ma app_ba hired_phd hired_ma hired_ba
1   a      6       4      1      3         4        1        1
2   b      4       4      1      2         4        0        0
3   c      3       0      1      6         0        1        2
4   d      2       1      1      1         1        1        0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(job = c("a","b","c","d"),
           needed = c(6,4,3,2),
           app_phd = c(4,4,0,1),
           app_ma = c(1,1,1,1),
           app_ba = c(3,2,6,1))

df %>% 
  mutate(hired_phd = ifelse(needed >= app_phd 
                            , app_phd, ifelse(needed >= 0, needed, 0)),
         
         hired_ma = ifelse(needed-app_phd >= app_ma 
                           , app_ma, ifelse(needed-app_phd >= 0, needed-app_phd, 0)),

         hired_ba = ifelse(needed-app_phd-app_ma >= app_ba
                           , app_ba, ifelse(needed-app_phd-app_ma >= 0, needed-app_phd-app_ma, 0))

         )

  job needed app_phd app_ma app_ba hired_phd hired_ma hired_ba
1   a      6       4      1      3         4        1        1
2   b      4       4      1      2         4        0        0
3   c      3       0      1      6         0        1        2
4   d      2       1      1      1         1        1        0
```

Comment: Thanks! More elegant than the messy "case_when" solution I was hacking together.